# Why are ListModel objects necessary?

Tags: java, swing, list, user-interface, collections

Let's say we have a list called JList1.

We want to create a model for it, so of course, we use a ListModel object. This is what would be done.

```
DefaultListModel<Integer> numbers = new DefaultListModel<>();
numbers.addElement(1);
numbers.addElement(2);
numbers.addElement(3);

jList2.setModel(numbers);
```

My question is why do we use a List Model object instead of a normal list or collection. The only reason that I know of is that `setModel()` only accepts list models as its argument, so what is the reason for these decisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the JavaDoc of [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) then you will realize that it provide several methods to manipulate the item in the `JList` that is not possible using simple collection.

If you initialize a list with an array or vector, the constructor implicitly creates a default list model. The default list model is immutable — you cannot add, remove, or replace items in the list. To create a list whose items can be changed individually, set the list's model to an instance of a mutable list model class, such as an instance of DefaultListModel.

Please have a look at the *Swing tutorial* on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating) where it is explained in detail.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why do we use a List Model object instead of a normal list or collection.

Swing follows a variation of the MVC (Model-View-Controller) design.

The Model has a couple of main responsibilities:

1. to hold the data
2. notify the View when the data changes so that the View can repaint itself.

Internally you will generally find that a Model will use a Collection implementation to store the data.

You can search the web for more information on MVC design. You may want to start with: [A Swing Architecture Overview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html) to understand how MVC is used in Swing.